# How to suppress FindBugs warning (hard coded reference to an absolute pathname)?

Tags: java, findbugs, absolute-path, suppress-warnings, hardcoded

i am just testing some things for the opensource software Geonetwork and now I want to export a shape file from my postGIS database to my computer but I cant test it cause I always get a findbugs warning : 
Hard coded reference to an absolute pathname in org.fao.geonet.services.resources.Download.exec(Element, ServiceContext)

Does anyone know how to suppress or to avoid this warning? Or another solution how I can test if the export works?

Here is the Code:

```
  ` Map parameter1= new HashMap();
    parameter1.put("dbtype", "postgis");        
    parameter1.put("host", "localhost");        
    parameter1.put("port", "5433");  
    parameter1.put("database", "geonetwork");
    parameter1.put("schema", "mydata");
    parameter1.put("user", "postgres");        
    parameter1.put("passwd", "dominik1");
    parameter1.put("Expose primary keys", false);
    parameter1.put(PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.VALIDATECONN, true);
    parameter1.put(PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.MAX_OPEN_PREPARED_STATEMENTS, 100);
    parameter1.put(PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.LOOSEBBOX, true);
    parameter1.put(PostgisNGDataStoreFactory.PREPARED_STATEMENTS, true); 
    System.out.println("parameter1: " + parameter1);

    DataStore pds = new PostgisNGDataStoreFactory().createDataStore(parameter1);
    FeatureSource fs = pds.getFeatureSource("dano");

    SimpleFeatureCollection fc = (SimpleFeatureCollection) fs.getFeatures();
    SimpleFeature f = (SimpleFeature) fc.toArray()[0];

    // create shapefile

    File sfile = new File("C:/Users/Tinis/Downloads/dano.zip");            
    parameter1 = new HashMap();
    parameter1.put("url", sfile.toURI().toURL());
    parameter1.put("create spatial index", Boolean.FALSE);


    DirectoryDataStore dds = new DirectoryDataStore(new File(sfile.getAbsolutePath()), (FileStoreFactory) new ShapefileDataStoreFactory.ShpFileStoreFactory(new ShapefileDataStoreFactory(), parameter1));    

    dds.createSchema(fc.getSchema());
    String typeName = dds.getTypeNames()[0];
    SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = dds.getFeatureSource(typeName);
    SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) featureSource;

    // write data to shapefile
    Transaction t = new DefaultTransaction("addTransaction");
    featureStore.setTransaction(t);
    featureStore.addFeatures(fc);
    t.commit();
    t.close(); `
```

The line which gives the findbugs warning is just after the // create shapefile comment

I hope someone can help me with this problem.
Thank you!

Comment: How are you using findbugs? (i.e. calling directly, using maven report, etc.)?

Comment: how is a findbugs _warning_ preventing you to run the code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make a xxx.properties file (ResourceBundle) with an entry:

```
danoZip = C:/Users/Tinis/Downloads/dano.zip
```

And do it indirect:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("xxx");

String danoZipPath = bundle.getString("danoZip");

File sfile = new File(danoZipPath);
```

**In this way you put the configuration of a hard-coded file in a configurable properties file.**

Comment: Thank you for answering!
Do you mean bundle.getString instead of bundle.get?

Comment: @PatrickGiersch of course, I will correct.

Comment: I tried this now but something has gone wrong!?
Exc : java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name shpprop, locale de_DE ------- 
My Code:   
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("shpprop");
String danoShpPath = bundle.getString("danoShp");
File sfile = new File(danoShpPath); --------
        
with shpprop.properties which is in the same package like my Java File: ------

danoShp = C:/Users/Tinis/Downloads/dano.shp

What did I wrong?

Comment: The path in getBundle is absolute, needs the package name as path. And a file `"shpprop.properties"`. Case-sensitive too. `getBundle("org.sioux.myapp.shprop")` though `/` is often used for .properties.

Comment: Thank you, working now. Can't give you vote up cause 15 reputation is needed. Anyway thank you very much! :-)

Comment: Just a typo: It must be `ResourceBundle.getBundle("xxx");`

Comment: @aProgger thanks, corrected

Answer (score 1):

You can use a filter file to describe bugs to ignore.

http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html

Comment: I have done it like this in the findbugs_excludes.xml:

<Match>
<Class name=""org.fao.geonet.services.resources.Download" />
</Match>

Then I run the package in Eclipse as "Maven Install" 
While installing I get the same error and after it the change which I made in findbugs_excludes.xml is undone.
Strange, why did this happen?